# How can I make a map where the value is an array of structs in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following structure.

```
struct Tourist {
  string name;
  string surname;
  string sex;
};
```

I would like to sort tourists by families.

```
int getMinRoomsAmount(Tourist touristsList[]) {
  map<string, Tourist[]> families;

  for (int i=0; i < 40; i++) {
    families[touristsList[i].surname] = // to append the array with the tourist
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to have a map where the key is a string, and the value is an array of structures?
And how can I append the array with new entries?

Comment: **Recommended reading:** https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: No, arrays cannot be objects. But `std::vector`s can be. This is what `std::vector` is for, so what you want is `std::map<std::string, std::vector<Tourist>>`, however if your goal is to sort it by surname, you don't even need that. just put everything in a single `std::vector` and use `std::sort` with a custom comparator lambda. Much simpler, and easier.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Arrays are absolutely objects.

Comment: If arrays are objects, then `a=b` would work, when both `a` and `b` are arrays. Obviously, that's not the case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Completely false. Assignability and being-an-object-ness are entirely orthogonal. You can trivially construct a class type that isn't assignable. Are its instances not objects?

Comment: The default assignment operator gets deleted only in very few circumstances. Specific exceptions don't prove or disprove the rule.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You're the one who introduced the notion that ability to assign is "obviously" equivalent to being an object. That is just not the case. I've provided a counter example. Now you're moving the goalposts. In fact, an object in C++ is a region of storage, and an array is an object with subobjects just as is a class instance with members. The inability to assign arrays is actually the exception. You can read more about it with some research.

Comment: Perhaps a `const int` isn't an object either 

Comment: Actually, fundamental rules of logic dictate that when "obviously" something is not X when it's not Y it must mean that "obviously" when something is X, it also must be Y. Happy to help, have a nice day.

Comment: It's always such a pleasure, @Sam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Map :** You could use a map of string and vector of Tourist - `map<string, std::vector<Tourist> >  families;` .
- **Insertion :** For adding a new element to a family, just use `push_back()`  method of vector as - `families[touristsList[i].surname].push_back(touristsList[i]);` . This statement will simply add the family(`Tourist` struct) to the map with key of surname.

---

Below is a working demo of your program -

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>


struct Tourist {
  std::string name;
  std::string surname;
  std::string sex;
};

int getMinRoomsAmount(std::vector<Tourist> touristsList) {
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<Tourist> >  families;

  for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {

    // to append the array with the tourist
    families[touristsList[i].surname].push_back(touristsList[i]);       

  }

  // iterating over the map and printing the Tourists families-wise
  for(auto it:families){
    std::cout<<"Family "<<it.first<<" : \n";
    for(auto family : it.second){
        std::cout<<family.name<<" "<<family.surname<<" "<<family.sex<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"\n-------\n";
  }

  return 0;
}


int main() {
    // making 3 struct objects just for demo purpose
    Tourist t1={"a1","b1","m"};
    Tourist t2={"a2","b1","f"};
    Tourist t3={"a3","b3","m"};
    // inserting the objects into vector and then passing it to the function
    std::vector<Tourist>t={t1,t2,t3};
    getMinRoomsAmount(t);

}
```

I have just included 3 Tourist objects for demo purpose. You can modify the code to suit your needs. I have used vectors instead of array because they are more efficient and you can dynamically push/pop as per the user inputs later on if you want to modify the program.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

You really want to stay away from arrays, especially when using `std::map`.  The `std::map` will copy your structure and arrays don't copy well.

Here is the definition of a map with value as an std::vector:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Tourist>>
```

Here is how to add to the map:

```
std::vector<Tourist> database;
Tourist t1{"x", "x", "x"};
Tourist t2{"y", "y", "y"};
Tourist t3{"z", "z", "z"};
database.pushback(t1);
database.pushback(t2);
database.pushback(t3);
// Check this out:
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Tourist>> visitors;
visitor["Italy"] = database;
```

Answer (score -3):

Use a map of string→`vector<Tourist>`.

Then use the vectors in the normal way, e.g. `push_back`.